# Are these 2 keras deep learning code the same for multiple outputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I've a problem involving airfoil velocity and pressure prediction, given the AOA,x,y. I'm using keras with MLP. I have 3 inputs (AOA,x,y) and I have to predict 3 outputs (u,v,p). I initially have a code which outputs the MSE loss as a single value. However, I modified the code so that I have MSE for each output. However, I don't get the avg MSE of the 3 outputs (u_mean_squared_error: 73.63%,v_mean_squared_error: 1.13%,p_mean_squared_error: 2.16%) equal to the earlier single MSE loss (mean_squared_error: 5.81%). Hence, I'm wondering if my new code is wrong. Or whether I'm doing it the right way. Can someone help?

Old code:

```
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("S1020_data.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input and output variables
X = dataset[:,0:3]
Y = dataset[:,3:6]

# split into 67% for train and 33% for test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=seed)

# create model
input_data = layers.Input(shape=(3,))

#create the layers and pass them the input tensor to get the output tensor:    
hidden1Out = Dense(units=12, activation='relu')(input_data)
hidden2Out = Dense(units=8, activation='relu')(hidden1Out)    
finalOut = Dense(units=3, activation='relu')(hidden2Out)   

#define the model's start and end points
model = Model(input_data, finalOut)

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=1000)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

New code:

```
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("S1020_data.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input and output variables
X = dataset[:,0:3]
Y = dataset[:,3:6]

# split into 67% for train and 33% for test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=seed)

# create model
input_data = layers.Input(shape=(3,))

#create the layers and pass them the input tensor to get the output tensor:    
hidden1Out = Dense(units=12, activation='relu')(input_data)
hidden2Out = Dense(units=8, activation='relu')(hidden1Out)    
u_out = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='u')(hidden2Out)   
v_out = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='v')(hidden2Out)   
p_out = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='p')(hidden2Out)   

#define the model's start and end points
model = Model(input_data,outputs = [u_out, v_out, p_out])

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, [y_train[:,0], y_train[:,1], y_train[:,2]], validation_data=(X_test,[y_test[:,0], y_test[:,1], y_test[:,2]]), epochs=10, batch_size=1000)

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, [Y[:,0], Y[:,1], Y[:,2]])

for i in range(7):
    print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[i], scores[i]*100))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to use model.predict to see if I will get a different ans. However, for the old code, with only a single MSE, I got : mean_squared_error: 5.46% [[0.69845194 0.         0.        ]. The 2nd and 3rd outputs are zero. However, if I change my activation in the output layer from relu to linear, I got [[ 0.93521696 -0.09542219  0.15364069]. Why is this so? Same for the new code with multiple MSE outputs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference comes from the optimization objective.

In your old code, the objective was:

sqrt( (u_true - u_pred)^2 + (v_true - v_pred)^2 + (p_true - p_pred)^2 )

which minimizes the 2-norm of the [u_pred,v_pred,p_pred] vector with respect to its target.

---

But in the new one, the objective became:

sqrt((u_true - u_pred)^2) + sqrt((v_true - v_pred)^2) + sqrt((p_true - p_pred)^2)

which is quite different from the previous one.